# Single SpecFlow test not showing up in test explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automated-tests, specflow

So, let me preface this with saying that I'm sure it's something small that I've forgotten, but not even my manager can figure out why this is happening. I have a single set of tests that I've written using SpecFlow. The structure we have uses a Dto file, a Page Object file, a Feature file and a Steps file. My setup:
VS 2019
SpecFlow for Visual Studio extension
<strike>Deveroom for SpecFlow (Visual Studio 2019)</strike>

Packages:
MongoDB.Bson, .Driver .Driver.Core 2.10.1
Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver 0.26.0
SpecFlow 3.1.78
SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation v 3.1.78
xunit.core, .extensibility.core, .extensibility.execution, .runner.visualstudio 2.4.1

Anything else, I can answer most questions, though it might take me time to find the answer. Yesterday, we updated to a .netcore framework, but that shouldn't have been the issue. The issue here is that I added 2 test groups, one for Banks and one for PlanSettings. I THINK I set them up identically:
First - created Dto file using Add New Item > C# Code File, the files are identically written and likely should be consolidated, but that's neither here nor there
Second - created Feature file using Add New Item > SpecFlow > SpecFlow Feature File and renamed to test name
Third - created Steps file using Add New Item > SpecFlow > SpecFlow Step Definition and renamed to the feature's test name with Steps added to the end
Fourth - wrote feature code and linked all steps to all step definitions
Fifth - Build and pray

Banks shows, Plan settings do not. I can attach code if necessary, but I'm not even sure what file the test is built off of. Will wait for advice before clarifying or proceeding. Would PREFER to not play around with extensions, but I will if I have to. My manager has never seen this before and advised to do more research.

What I have done:
Regenerated Feature Files
Commented out all new code and only kept older known working (on a different test) code
Rinse and repeated code - this was happening before we migrated to the .net code, so I had to rewrite a lot of what i did anyway, why not?
Swapped around extensions - this REALLY broke my before .net repo

Both tests were written on the same day within a few hours of each other by the same engineer. The ONLY difference is that the more senior automation engineer is out right now, so he didn't assist me in the set up process, but again, that shouldn't matter as I also had to rewrite the bank code after the migration, and that one works fine.

Thanks in advance

Clarification answers:
Yes, I wrote two tests - one shows, one does not
feature.cs files have identical top portions, but here is the entire file:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  <auto-generated>
//      This code was generated by SpecFlow (http://www.specflow.org/).
//      SpecFlow Version:3.1.0.0
//      SpecFlow Generator Version:3.1.0.0
// 
//      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//      the code is regenerated.
//  </auto-generated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#region Designer generated code
#pragma warning disable
namespace Abarca.Tests.UI.SpecFlow.Features.Clients.ClientBenefitSetup
 {
        using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
        using System;
    using System.Linq;
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("TechTalk.SpecFlow", "3.1.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
public partial class ClientBenefitSetupBenefitPlanSettingsFeature : object, Xunit.IClassFixture<ClientBenefitSetupBenefitPlanSettingsFeature.FixtureData>, System.IDisposable
{

    private static TechTalk.SpecFlow.ITestRunner testRunner;

    private string[] _featureTags = ((string[])(null));

    private Xunit.Abstractions.ITestOutputHelper _testOutputHelper;

#line 1 "ClientBenefitSetupBenefitPlanSettings.feature"
#line hidden

    public ClientBenefitSetupBenefitPlanSettingsFeature(ClientBenefitSetupBenefitPlanSettingsFeature.FixtureData fixtureData, Abarca_Tests_UI_XUnitAssemblyFixture assemblyFixture, Xunit.Abstractions.ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
    {
        this._testOutputHelper = testOutputHelper;
        this.TestInitialize();
    }

    public static void FeatureSetup()
    {
        testRunner = TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner();
        TechTalk.SpecFlow.FeatureInfo featureInfo = new 
TechTalk.SpecFlow.FeatureInfo(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), 
"ClientBenefitSetupBenefitPlanSettings", "\tThis feature tests all 
functionalities contained in the Benefit Plan Settings sc" +
                "reen under the LOB Section of the Client Benefit Setup.", ProgrammingLanguage.CSharp, ((string[])(null)));
        testRunner.OnFeatureStart(featureInfo);
    }

    public static void FeatureTearDown()
    {
        testRunner.OnFeatureEnd();
        testRunner = null;
    }

    public virtual void TestInitialize()
    {
    }

    public virtual void TestTearDown()
    {
        testRunner.OnScenarioEnd();
    }

    public virtual void ScenarioInitialize(TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
    {
        testRunner.OnScenarioInitialize(scenarioInfo);
        testRunner.ScenarioContext.ScenarioContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<Xunit.Abstractions.ITestOutputHelper>(_testOutputHelper);
    }

    public virtual void ScenarioStart()
    {
        testRunner.OnScenarioStart();
    }

    public virtual void ScenarioCleanup()
    {
        testRunner.CollectScenarioErrors();
    }

    public virtual void FeatureBackground()
    {
#line 4
 #line hidden
        TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table table169 = new TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table(new string[] {
                    "attribute",
                    "value"});
        table169.AddRow(new string[] {
                    "User",
                    "Automation"});
        table169.AddRow(new string[] {
                    "Password",
                    "@Abca123"});
        table169.AddRow(new string[] {
                    "UserType",
                    "Employee"});
#line 5
 testRunner.Given("I have successfully logged in to Darwin", ((string)(null)), table169, "Given ");
#line hidden
#line 10
 testRunner.And("I access the Client Benefit Setup option in the menu", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "And ");
#line hidden
        TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table table170 = new TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table(new string[] {
                    "attribute",
                    "value"});
        table170.AddRow(new string[] {
                    "SearchId",
                    "abca"});
#line 11
 testRunner.And("I filter by the ID column within the Client Benefit Setup List screen", ((string)(null)), table170, "And ");
#line hidden
#line 14
 testRunner.And("I press the Edit link for the filtered record within the Client Benefit Setup scr" +
                "een", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "And ");
#line hidden
#line 15
 testRunner.And("I press the Line of Business link within the Clients Edit screen", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "And ");
#line hidden
        TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table table171 = new TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table(new string[] {
                    "attribute",
                    "value"});
        table171.AddRow(new string[] {
                    "SearchId",
                    "020"});
#line 16
 testRunner.And("I filter by the ID column within the Line Of Business List screen", ((string)(null)), table171, "And ");
#line hidden
#line 19
 testRunner.And("I press the Edit link for the filtered record within the Line of Business List sc" +
                "reen", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "And ");
#line hidden
#line 20
 testRunner.And("I press the Benefit Plans link within the Line of Business Edit screen", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "And ");
#line hidden
        TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table table172 = new TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table(new string[] {
                    "attribute",
                    "value"});
        table172.AddRow(new string[] {
                    "SearchId",
                    "020"});
#line 21
 testRunner.And("I filter by the ID column within the Benefit Plans List screen", ((string)(null)), table172, "And ");
#line hidden
#line 24
 testRunner.And("I press the Edit link for the filtered record within the Benefit Plans List scree" +
                "n", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "And ");
#line hidden
#line 25
 testRunner.And("I press the Benefit Plan Settings link within the Benefit Plans screen", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "And ");
#line hidden
        TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table table173 = new TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table(new string[] {
                    "attribute",
                    "value"});
        table173.AddRow(new string[] {
                    "SearchId",
                    "020"});
#line 26
 testRunner.And("I filter by the Name column within the Benefit Plan Settings screen", ((string)(null)), table173, "And ");
#line hidden
#line 29
 testRunner.And("I press the Edit link for the filtered record within the Benefit Plans Settings L" +
                "ist screen", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "And ");
#line hidden
    }

    void System.IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        this.TestTearDown();
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("TechTalk.SpecFlow", "3.1.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    public class FixtureData : System.IDisposable
    {

        public FixtureData()
        {
            ClientBenefitSetupBenefitPlanSettingsFeature.FeatureSetup();
        }

        void System.IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            ClientBenefitSetupBenefitPlanSettingsFeature.FeatureTearDown();
        }
    }
}
}
#pragma warning restore
#endregion
```

(I apologize for the formatting)

Comment: Can you revert back to a working solution( restore). And the update one component at a time to see what breaks it?

Comment: I would, but the test has never shown in test explorer. The repo, itself, works fine. All other tests are working as usual. It's just this one, single test that's not showing up

Comment: You can't have both extensions: SpecFlow for VS and Deveroom for SpecFlow.
You have to choose one. Look [here](https://www.specsolutions.eu/services/deveroom/) under Installation section.But anyway, your problem will persist.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll edit the question. It looks like Deveroom was disabled.

Comment: So, let me clarify: you have added 2 tests? and one is visible and another is not visible in test explorer?

Comment: Yes, I have written 2 tests under the same directory. One shows up in test explorer and works. The other does not. To me, it feels like this is an easy answer, but I've not been able to come up with the solution.

Comment: Don't you also need SpecFlow.XUnit reference from NuGet package? Otherwise build would fail.

Comment: Can you go in .feature.cs file (code behind of feature file) and search for that scenario that is not show inside test explorer? Search for that Plan settings that is not shown.

Comment: Maybe you could try go to %TEMP% location in your folder explorer. And delete .cache files for specflow. And reopen VS instance, and check for scenarios in Test Explorer.

Comment: Pasting the feature.cs file to the original question to let you see, but it's identical to the bank one that does show up

Comment: Ok, now give us FULL content of your feature file for PlanSettings.

Comment: Just dumped the cache for all of my repos (just to be thorough) in %TEMP%. Still no dice.

Comment: And the full feature.cs file is pasted above (after fighting with the interface a tad)

Comment: RESOLVED! I forgot a Scenario!